# Rails' resource has 'show' mapped without an ID and creates /users.id links instead of /users/id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

For my current routing, the following ruby on rails code:

```
<%= link_to current_user.name, users_path(current_user) %>
```

which produces a link like the following:

```
<a href="/users.1">name</a>
```

In turn, Ruby on Rails has a hard time understanding this as it expects the `1` to be the format:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show 
  Couldn't find User without an ID

Request
  Parameters: 
  {"format"=>"1"}
```

Which doesn't exactly make sense for Rails to route it like that, since it much rather should be `/users/1`. Trying this by hand, however, gives the following result:

```
Routing Error
  No route matches "/users/1"
```

Having the ID entered per hand with an ?id= param, such as `/users?id=1`, works fine.

The issue is, I don't understand where the users.id comes from, nor how to fix - my routing file looks like

```
routes::Application.routes.draw do
  get "register" => "users#new", :as => "register"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  post "login" => "sessions#create", :as => "do_login"
  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"

  resource :users

  root :to => "pages#welcome"
end
```

All actions but the one mentioned above work fine, though I'd like to find out why. `rake routes` lays it out like the following:

```
     users POST   /users(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
 new_users GET    /users/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
           GET    /users(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
           PUT    /users(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
           DELETE /users(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

The issue here seems to be that users#show seems to have taken the place of users#index, which would be the correct thing to do for /users. Since this is all pretty much default routing with no custom routes in terms of the issue on hand, I'm quite clueless here. Any ideas?

Edit: The users#show code is as simple as:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want your route to use `resources :users`, not `resource :users`.

Also, change your `link_to` to use `user_path` instead of `users_path`:

```
<%= link_to current_user.name, user_path(current_user) %>
```